# How to read a certain line from a string via PHP?

Tags: php, string

I have a string I get via POST request, which is a config file, and I'd like to read a certain line from the string.

How can I do that?

I know of SplFileObject, but it's only for files and not for string, and I really prefer to not have to move the string into a file just for the sake of this.

Comment: Show us your string and your code/attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I don't know how to begin doing that, since it's a string and not a file.

Comment: See the documentation of http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.construct.php

Comment: @RonMelkhior Take a look at `explode()` to get your string into an array.

Comment: Please see my edit, that's a function for files, and I have a string. @ Rizier I'll take a look. Thanks.

Comment: See my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119040/how-to-read-a-certain-line-from-a-string-via-php?noredirect=1#comment55986995_34119040 regarding the wrappers. And http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php about the different wrappers e.g. memory or tmp. Or php://input if it is in the raw post body.